How can I connect ABS pipe to a lead pipe cut flush to a slab?
TLDR:

flush cut 2" lead drain for shower on concrete
how to make new connection to ABS when rebuilding shower?

I'm currently remodeling my downstairs bathroom which is in the basement so on concrete. House is from 76, looks like the previous 2" lead pipe was cut flush to slab, or even a little under flush. I am planning on using the kerdi drain kit flange kit ( p/n: KD2/ABS/E). So from here, what do I do to make a solid connection to the lead portion? I've seen posts referring to use a 2" banded/shielded coupling but can't find any lead to plastic specific ones.
I'm assuming I should chisel away away a little around the connection but don't want to go in blind. How would you tackle this and make a solid connection to the lead pipe, or am I supposed to go all the way down to the cast iron connection (but then I have the same questions/problems)?
Also, it looks like the lead pipe connects to a cast iron pipe at the p-trap, at least from the iron/rust dust building up on the lower part.



I don't know where that pipe goes, but the degrading iron section concerns me. I'd want that fixed before I bury it all with a shower. It's often not the nightmare folks tend to assume to open up a slab for repairs.

Please take the [tour] so you know how to respond to answers. I see that you have an earlier question with answers you haven't addressed.

What makes you think it's lead?
